# PTR records support on azure

Tags: azure, dns

We are currently working on project which allow users to create their own sites. Users are able to bind their own domain to site created in our system. One of our feature is support email for users domains. So we need email service 
which will be able to host a lot of domains. We created such service but when we send emails from our service receiver service put them to spam folder (such behaviour was detected at least for gmail and yahooo). 
As we know you have problems with support of PTR records. Is it possible to set it up to send requests for DNS REVERS LOOKUP (requests for getting PTR records) to our service (we also have our own DNS service)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently no.

But this is very demanded feature: http://bit.ly/azureptr give your 3 votes to help it happens. As it appears MSFT is already looking into it! Also if you comment on the feature requires, you will make more impact to final decisions!

Comment: Do you know where we can host our email server to achive our aim?

Comment: Hopefully Azure will very soon be the place. Until then you have to search for alternatives like Amazon Web Services with their Route53 support.

Comment: They've been "looking in to it" last 2 years... don't hold you breath

Answer (score 2):

Provide Reverse DNS (PTR records) for Virtual Machines in Azure is completed. See: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/21/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/

Adding reverse DNS to existing Cloud Services

```
PS C:\> Set-AzureService –ServiceName “contosoapp1” –Description “App1 with Reverse DNS” –ReverseDnsFqdn “contosoapp1.cloudapp.net.”
```

Creating a new Cloud Service with reverse DNS

```
PS C:\> New-AzureService –ServiceName “contosoapp1” –Location “West US” –Description “App1 with Reverse DNS” –ReverseDnsFqdn “contosoapp1.cloudapp.net.”
```

Viewing the reverse DNS for an existing Cloud Service

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureService "contosoapp1"
```

Removing reverse DNS from existing Cloud Services

```
PS C:\> Set-AzureService –ServiceName “contosoapp1” –Description “App1 with Reverse DNS” –ReverseDnsFqdn “”
```