# How can I configure a DNS PTR records in Azure dns service…?

Tags: azure, dns

How can I configure a DNS PTR records in Azure dns service…?
 I don’t find the PTR records un Azure DNS

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is that you can't because as of today (11th May 2016), Azure DNS doesn't support PTR records.

Answer (score 0):

PTR records are primarily used for reverse lookups and are used in the in-addr.arpa reverse lookup domain. the reverse lookup domains are managed by the owners of the IP Address range that you are using. Since you can't use your own (public) address range on Azure, you can't add reverse domains, and hence you don't need to add PTR records.

You can add reverse look up for some services on Azure such as VMs, if you can advise what your use case is we can probably help you figure out what you should do.

Comment: I need to associate a public static Azure IP address that point to a azure SQL data base, the enterprisse sec policy only allow ip rules. Azure SQL DB only gives DNs names to access the SQL Service.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up here since you want to have a `PTR` for an Azure IP (top of search results) this needs to be configured "by" Microsoft, and should not live in your own DNS zones.

While I have not tested this myself (yet) it might be useful to read
https://medium.com/@lassiuosukainen/how-i-setup-reverse-dns-on-azure-c09c56e3636d

Where Powershell is used to configure a PTR for already existing public IP

```
$pip = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name “name-of-azure--ip” -ResourceGroupName “resourcegroup-name”
$pip.DnsSettings = New-Object -TypeName “Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSPublicIpAddressDnsSettings”
$pip.DnsSettings.DomainNameLabel = “Label for dns record?”
$pip.DnsSettings.ReverseFqdn = “Your.domain.FQDN.tld."
Set-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -PublicIpAddress $pip
```

A different approach can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25303990/2716218